# What is good software to use for simple database design?

Tags: windows, database, design

I just want to lay out the tables and represent their relationships, I don't need fancy, but if fancy is free/cheap and simple to use, please share. I have tried lucid chart, but want to know if there is anything better or that works for you, all opinions welcome, preferably cheap or free as the database doesn't need to be too complex, I would prefer not to waste paper.

I'm working on Windows, and the tool should at least support MySQL.

Comment: What OS should it run on? And what databases should it support?

Comment: @Izzy, so sorry.

os => windows
database => MySQL

Comment: Thanks! I've integrated that with your question. Are you by chance also use a PHP enabled web server on the same machine as MySQL? If so, phpMyAdmin might be worth a look, as it includes a simple "designer". AFAIR its "Modeller" (often used to graphically visualize relations) can be used for that as well.